# Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, arabic, character-encoding

I have changed the charset of the tables and of the column, i get the arabic text as ???? marks in MYSQL database

here is the design of the table

```
  CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;


   CREATE TABLE `categories` (                        
   `category_id` tinyint(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,           
   `category_name` varchar(50)character set utf8 NOT NULL ,  
   PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`) 


   insert into `mydb`.`categories` 
    (`category_id`, `category_name`)
    values (1,'کتگوری');
   commit;
```

When I again fire select query it shows ???? as text?

Can anyone tell me where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of mysql? How are you displaying your text? can you give the code you are using to retrieve the data back? I'm using the same encoding and collation and it works fine for me.

Comment: Mysql version 5.0.45. using select query.. select * from poll_categories

Comment: This works for me in MySQL WB

Comment: It should work. As answers suggest, make sure that you use the correct encoding in the client side. What client are you using here?

Comment: After the connection to MySql in PHP, do `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);`. But please consider moving away from `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated and no longer supported in PHP 7.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To insert Arabic Data manually into your Phpmyadmin.

First you check either your database , table and column name is utf8 set or not.
If these are not set to utf8 then first you set it then you may insert arabic data into you db table.

## YOU MAY CHECK EACH OF THESE BY LOOKING BELOW EXAMPLE.

For Database:

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S
WHERE schema_name = "schemaname";
```

For Tables:

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "schemaname"
  AND T.table_name = "tablename";
```

For Columns:

```
SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C
WHERE table_schema = "schemaname"
  AND table_name = "tablename"
  AND column_name = "columnname";
```

You may easily set utf8 to your tables if you are using SQLYog.

Just right click on db, table, column name and click on alter option and set to

Database Chartset = utf8
Database Collation = utf8_general_ci .

Just Enjoy ....

Comment: specially, please check the individual column character encoding, that's what had me scratching my head for quiet long.

Comment: Simpler with just `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`

Answer (score 26):

To read ,write and sort Arabic text in mysql database using php correctly, make sure that:

1. MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
2. MySQL connection collation: `utf8_general_ci`
3. your database and table collations are set to: `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`

Then, add this code in your php script when you connect to db:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

[For more details](http://www.adviesenzo.nl/examples/php_mysql_charset_fix/)

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_query`; switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 17):

We can convert database or db table to uft8 supportive with below query:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE columnname DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Hope it helps !

Read More @

https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/138/Default+MySQL+character+set+and+collation#gs

http://hollyslog.com/technology/how-to-store-arabic-or-hebrew-characters-mysql-database

Comment: Caution!  That last `ALTER` could mangle data even worse.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Answer (score 5):

Change the database tables collations types to `utf8_general_ci` and also table fields collations change to `utf8_general_ci`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nadeem Ijaz

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your client software is also using UTF-8.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
$conn = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$dbname);
$conn->set_charset("UTF8");
```

Comment: Hi @Waseem Thank you for answering. Can you please explain why your answer is good and how it solves the question

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.categories         
(category_id tinyint(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,category_name MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (category_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

```
            // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml  properties
            Properties settings = new Properties();
            
            settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alizidan?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
            settings.put(Environment.USER, "root");
            settings.put(Environment.PASS, "");
            settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
            // does not work with my sql settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_CHARSET_NAME, "UTF-8");
```

// characterEncoding=UTF-8  at "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alizidan?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=UTF-8" work VERY GOOD

```
            settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

            settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");

    //        settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");

            configuration.setProperties(settings);
```