# how to store arabic font in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding, collation

i WANT TO store Arabic words in my table of dictionary.

i am using a java script code for typing Arabic in a text box.

it is working fine.

After insertion into table when i get all the records, it properly shows Arabic words.

but in my table Arabic words store in this format
򂠏&#980980 ETC

Not in this format
باالالا

that creates a problem for me.
When i want to search any Arabic word from my table using  word = $arabic OR

using word LIKE `'%$arabic%'`

it fails and shows no result.

Please help me for this problem.

**NOTE**

When i write query in query editor it store Arabic font in Arabic format.

I am using  utf8-bin collation for Arabic column.

Comment: Read [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: please check your charset and collation of database and table they be same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2):

change your table(columns) collation to `utf8_general_ci` and also in your html add

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: are you sure it will solve this have you read this anywhere ??

Comment: I just encoutered this issue 2 days before and I inserted arabic letters in my database by changing the column collation to utf8_general_ci

Comment: It would be recommended to avoid `utf8_general_ci` and instead use `utf8_unicode_ci` for collation. Here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/558866

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following things:
1.set the UTF-8 in your php script,like this:

```
 ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

2.make the **Collation** as **utf8_general_ci** in database.

Answer (score 1):

Set:

MySQL table charset to utf8, collation to utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci. and in your code(connection string) also set charset to utf8.

Answer (score 0):

you should ensure that the html support arabic text by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

you should also check the encoding in your database , it should be `utf8_unicode_ci` or ther simalar encoding