# Arabic language in php/mysql appears "????" question marks in html

Tags: php, mysql, encode, arabic, html-encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

I have a problem with retrieving Arabic data from MYSQL database using PHP, it appears as question marks "????" in HTML:

1. I have a database with "utf8_general_ci" as collation.
2. The database contains some data in Arabic Language.
3. The HTML encoding is "UTF-8".
4. When I tried to retrieve the data in HTML, it appears as "?????".

Please Help !!!

Comment: After you connect to the database, execute this query `"SET NAMES utf8"` before retrieving data.

Comment: There are everal steps where things _can_ go wrong if any component of the tool chain is configured _not_ to use UTF-8. So in the end you will have to check at all stations where the data travels through to find that place where the encoding is suddenly broken.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 52, accepted):

you must set charset in first connect with mysql by this query:

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

for example in mysqli functions

```
$MySQL_Handle = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME,DATABASE_USERNAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME) 
or die ( mysqli_error($MySQL_Handle) ); 

$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($MySQL_Handle,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase');
```

and PDO sample :

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $DB_NAME, $DB_USER,
$DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
$dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
```

this action need before insert and before select.