# utf8 (arabic) string appears as question mark (?)

Tags: java, mysql, kotlin, encoding, vert.x

I am using version 3.8.2 and having some issues with utf8 string appears as question mark (?) in the database when inserting new record, but it's display old record correctly (inserted using phpmyadmin).

here how i init MySQLPool

```
fun init(vertx: Vertx): MySQLPool {
    val connectOptions = MySQLConnectOptions()
      .setPort(Config.mysqlPort)
      .setHost(Config.mysqlHost)
      .setDatabase(Config.mysqlDatabase)
      .setUser(Config.mysqlUsername)
      .setPassword(Config.mysqlPassword)
      .setCharset("utf8") // tried utf8mb4 also same result
      .setCollation("utf8_general_ci") // also tried utf8mb4_general_ci

    val poolOptions = PoolOptions().setMaxSize(Config.maxPoolSize)

    return MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions)
}
```

**mysql variables**

```
character_set_client        = utf8
character_set_connection    = utf8
character_set_database      = utf8
character_set_filesystem    = binary
character_set_results       = utf8
character_set_server        = utf8mb4
character_set_system        = utf8
```

**table collation**

utf8_general_ci

**mysql create table**

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` text NOT NULL,
  `Image` text NOT NULL,
  `Link` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `Summery` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `Story` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `Time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(6) ON UPDATE current_timestamp(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thank you

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: no they are not the same since this is jvm encoding issue and not mysql, so i wouldn't say this is duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's seems the default charset in jvm is set to **windows-1252** changing it to **UTF-8** solved it

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")
val charset = Charset::class.java.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset")
charset.isAccessible = true
charset.set(null,null)
```

the **setCharset("utf8")** and **setCollation("utf8_general_ci")** options are configured at the connection level, but not really have an effects on charset for encoding, that why the encoding value is encoded in the default jvm charset

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer of your question [Arabic language in php/mysql appears "????" question marks in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439324/arabic-language-in-php-mysql-appears-question-marks-in-html)

you must set charset in first connect .

Comment: yes i have tried this way with no luck, though using jdbc client worked perfectly fine

Comment: This link solves the problem with phpMyAdmin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1NMU-hZ7mY @BadrAzizi