# PHPspreadsheet and JS: How to support arabic?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I'm getting data from the database, some strings are English, some are Arabic, some are half Arabic half English.

I'm generating the spreadsheet `.xlsx` like this

```
function writeToFile($spreadsheet, $filename)
{
    header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

    $writer->save("php://output");
}
```

But I'm not downloading it directly, this generates a blob which gets downloaded using javascript.

```
fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.blob())
    .then(file => {
        if (file.size > 0) {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        } else {
             console.log('error');
        }
    })
    .catch(() => console.log('error'));
```

The problem is with PHPspreadsheet, I don't know if I fix that, I'll get another problem related to JS, but I do know that if I generate the file without using JS, I'll still have the Arabic issue.

Comment: What if you download the `.xlsx` directly without js, is it encoded correctly then?

Comment: @Patrick I'll try that just to see if it works but even then, that won't be an option because by downloading it without JS, I'd have to open a new tab and won't know if the file is empty or not before downloading it.

Comment: the idea is to figure out if the error occurs on PHP side og JS side

Comment: @Patrick just tested it. The problem is with PHPspreadsheet, I don't know if I fix that, I'll get another problem related to JS, but I do know that if I generate the file without using JS, I'll still have the Arabic issue.

Comment: What about to save the file first on directory and then download the result?

Comment: @Sundance_Raphael tried that, tried to save to a directory and then viewed the file created in the directory without any download. The Arabic part is still messed up.

Comment: Have you but the right spelling direktion to the arabic thinks?

Comment: @Sundance_Raphael, No, I don't even see the letters, I see question marks `????`

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue are you sure that you use an encoding in excel that understand arabic characters? The standard encoding is "Westeuropäuisch" means has no set for arrabic characters.

Comment: @Sundance_Raphael My excel is perfectly able to read arabic, I opened and viewed [this sample file](http://www.meabank.com/sites/default/files/Personal%20Loan%20Application.xlsx) successfully, are you able to write an example arabic spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439324/arabic-language-in-php-mysql-appears-question-marks-in-html), It turns out I need to add

```
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'")
```

To the PDO connection, so it becomes like this

```
 try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $db;
}
```