# I am trying to upload file that have arabic

Tags: php, upload, arabic

I am trying to upload a file that has an Arabic name like (مرحبا بكم)

But when I upload it to server the name is not correct, it shows characters like that (Ø±ÙŠÙ-Ù).

So, how can I upload files with Arabic name?

Code:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post your current solution, so how you currently upload the file.

Comment: Check this answer, hope it help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/43273146/7272278

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode the name in unicode.
you could use `base64_encode($filename)` to save the name of the file