# My Arabic data is getting converted into ???? after editing the arabic data and saving it through php

Tags: php, html

I have some Arabic data in my json and i want to make changes in  it  through some editor  and saving it  through php then all my data is getting converted into ???? .i tried using all the encoding standards but i did not get  the result .

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: maybe similar to this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Comment: Are you using the correct character encoding in your html?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you're using the right content-type with the right character encoding, eg: `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. Ensure you're checking the encoding type of the data coming in, and ensure you're using the correct encoding type type in your connection to the DB, and that the table itself is using the correct encoding type.