# How to insert Persian link in database?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, insert, persian

I cant insert persian link in databse;

Example:

False:

`http://jik545.ir/item-444352-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B1%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4-%D8%AF%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%B0%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%87%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C.html`

True:

`http://jik545.ir/item-444352-رزمایش-دریایی-ایران-برای-مذاکرات-هسته-ای.html`

Could you please help me to achieve this?

Comment: **related :** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Comment: or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: ... actually, that looks like it's url-encoded; and since it's an URL it's probably correct; just chuck it into http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and you'll see what I mean - you could probably run it through `urldecode()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) before entering it into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Set the collation on the table/database/field to utf8

Comment: You missed the database connector

Comment: If you have done this, then the data should be stored as utf8. To retrieve it set also mysqli_set_charset() to utf8

Comment: Possibly, but that could be down to it's settings. If you would store it in utf-8, retrieve it in UTF8 and display it in UTF8 it would work.