# storing Arabic in to mysql

Tags: mysql, encoding, store, arabic

I have a problem related to Arabic encoding and storing Arabic in to mysql.

i applied all the following steps:

set MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Set MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

Set database and table collations are set to:utf8_general_ci
orutf8_unicode_ci

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

however the problem still exist.

Arabic values appear like this in mysql table: Ø£Ø­&Ugr.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

(Too many questions for a 'comment'.)

Are you using PHP?  If so, use mysqli_* intervace, not mysql_*.

set_charset('utf8') should suffice, not most of the rest of the actions.

Is that supposed to look something like 'ɣɭ&Ugr'?  If so, I think you have "double encoding".  Please pick some cell in the table and do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` so I can further analyze it.

(I am puzzled, because it looks more like some obscure latin encoding than Arabic.)

"Collation" is not relevant at this point; it may become important as we debug this.