# Yii store urdu or arabic word in database

Tags: mysql, yii

i want to store urdu word in database and in the database they should store ???????? this value
In yii database connection charset =>'utf8'
table type is utf8_general_ci
using Yii framework php

Comment: Have you tried this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.config` file should be like this:

```
'components' => array(
    ...
    'db' => array(
        ...
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'initSQLs'=>'SET NAMES utf8 ;',
    ),

),
```

Comment: 'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=e_promotion',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'schemaCachingDuration' => 1,
        ),

Comment: sir my db connection setting

Comment: Follow [this documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/16/how-to-set-up-unicode/). Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's 'utf8' is a 3-byte lie. Use `utf8mb4` instead for all your settings (both table definitions and connection settings) if you want to correctly handle all UTF-8 characters.

[See documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

Comment: sir only set db collations