# Insert an Arabic text MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

I'm trying to store an Arabic text to the table, I searched a lot but I didn't find a solution that worked for me, so this is what I got:

```
$en = "OK";
$ar = "حسناً";
$link->query("INSERT INTO words (en,ar) VALUES ($en,$ar)");
```

The problem is when I insert it, the Arabic text looks like `Ø­Ø³Ù†Ø§Ù‹`, my table's collation and MySQL's are `utf8_general_ci`, so is my database's, I also have `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Comment: @MariM All answers there didn't work for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently had the same issues myself.

Here's a few pointers:

- ALL attributes must be set to ut8 (collation is NOT the same as charset)
- Save the document as UTF-8 (If you're using Notepad++, it's Format -> Convert to UFT-8)
- The header in both PHP and HTML should be set to UTF-8 (HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- Upon connecting to the databse, set the charset ti UTF-8 there as well, like this: `$link->set_charset("utf8");` (directly after connecting)
- Also make sure your database and tables are set to UTF-8, you can do that like this:

`ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Remember that EVERYTHING needs to be set to UFT-8 charcode, or else it'll insert stuff like "Ø­Ø³Ù†Ø§Ù‹". Hope this helped!

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` has fixed my problem, thanks.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance! Don't forget to tag the answer as correct if it helped :)

Comment: Is there anything I can do to change the text in table column data, I already entered data from another table?

Comment: If the data is already inserted with a broken encoding, its not easy to fix it. The best way is to re-insert or update the data. There are some tools that has been made that forces UTF8, but none that can be relied on 100%.

Comment: Thanx a lot @Qire

Answer (score 4):

First thing is the database, table, and column. See if `utf8` is set:
`utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`

Also, the connection collation: utf8_general_ci

In PHP, after I connect with mysqli, I issue this:

```
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

And the web page output always jams in:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: They're all `utf8_general_ci`, I really don't know what's the problem

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` has fixed my problem, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

1. when you create the database choose the collation for: `utf8_unicode_ci`
2. when you connect to the database from php use the following character set:

   ```
   $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=record;charset=utf8";
   ```