# I can not store Arabic data in mysql , utf8 or cp1256 has not solve my issue

Tags: php, mysql

My database and tables inside database collation is utf8_general_ci 
My connection php file is as follows :

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW,DBNAME);

if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, DBNAME);
mysqli_query($connection,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

I even add a header to my connection.php file as follows :

```
header('content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Now when i try to insert Arabic characters into database i got this :

```
&#1593; &#1580; &#16
```

i also tried to do this :

```
mysqli_query($connection,"SET NAMES 'cp1256'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET CHARACTER SET cp1256");
```

But i still get the same result stored in my database.
Any idea please ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Comment: i searched and none of the existing answers helped my solve my issue

Comment: Check this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459458/insert-an-arabic-text-mysql

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this header('content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
2. mysqli_query($connection,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
3. MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci
4. And save the file of your code in utf-8.

If you use note++

look at this image

[image]

Comment: Thanks , And i add <form accept-charset="UTF8"> and problem solved :)

Comment: Use utf8mb4 encoding. you can not store emojy if you use utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Thanks for the note , I will consider changing the database collate to utf8b4 because i will use emoji icons for sure :)