# Data is not inserting to the database correctly by php

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

when i query in phpmyadmin

like

```
insert into table('نچجاعجان');
```

it display correctly but when i try to insert by php page it displays in the field like this:

> ÙØ§Ù†Ù†Ù†Ø§ÙÙ†Ø¹Ù†

My table collation is utf8 general ci and my column collation is also utf8 general ci. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What charset is your db connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Comment: phpmyadmin :Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) and when i echo this function mysql_client_encoding() i get latin1

Answer (score 0):

ok, you also need to set the character set from your code connection side. this can be done with:

```
 mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
 mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

Although I would strongly recommend you dont use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and you are putting a limited lifespan on your code. Its seriously worth looking at moving to mysqli_* functions - the learning curve is quite easy and it will open up a whole new world of coding possibilities for you ;)