# mysql PHPMyAdmin isn't accepting Arabic Language

Tags: php, android, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I am using an android app that connects on php files that insert values in mysql database. the problem is the database isn't saving the arabic input correctly but in strange characters. I searched the internet and tried to set everything to UTF-8 .. but it seems there is something missing .. what is it?

edit: this is solved by adding the below command after connecting to the mysql:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

1. I changed the database collation to utf8_general_ci as per below pic:

   [image]

   (I don't know how to alter Latin1_Swedish_ci) ?!!
2. changed the table collation to utf8_general_ci.
3. Changed the column collation to utf8_general_ci.
4. set the php auditor to utf-8.
5. I put that in the php file start:

   I also used utf8 in coding my variables in the android app before sending to php files.

Comment: what you didn't post (or probably didn't try) was to pass utf-8 to the connection before querying; try that. As outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks man, you saved my day :)

Comment: @SheriffSaidElahl You're most welcome, *cheers!* ;-)

Comment: The "database" setting is not relevant; check the column/table with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.