# MySQL + phpMyAdmin - Server Connection Collation vs Database Collation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

From phpMyAdmin I can see **Database Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)**.

The collation of all my databases, tables and columns is `utf8_unicode_ci`.

However, it shows my **Server connection collation** is `utf8_general_ci`.

It seems from phpMyAdmin, under server's general settings I can temporarily change it to `utf8_unicode_ci`. After I switch databases, it goes back to `utf8_general_ci`.

How do I change it permanently? Should I do it? Any side-effects?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database