# I want to write a file in utf8 in laravel that will place exact data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, utf-8

I want to write a file in utf8 format that will store same data as it is in database. But now it is writing  following data.

```
[{"id":1,"ar":"\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647","en":"Allah","bn":"\u0986\u09b2\u09cd\u09b2\u09be\u09b9 ","desc":"\u0986\u09b2\u09cd\u09b2\u09be\u09b9 \u09ae\u09b9\u09be\u09a8 \u0964 \u0986\u09b2\u09cd\u09b2\u09be\u09b9 \u0986\u09ae\u09be\u09a6\u09c7\u09b0 \u09b8\u09c3\u09b7\u09cd\u099f\u09bf \u0995\u09b0\u09c7\u099b\u09c7\u09a8\u0964 ","created_at":"2016-10-10 13:17:30","updated_at":"2016-10-10 13:17:30"},{"id":2,"ar":"\u062c\u0627\u0621","en":"come","bn":"\u0986\u09b8\u09be","desc":"\u0986\u09b8\u09be \u0964 \u0995\u09cb\u09a5\u09be\u0993 \u0986\u09b8\u09be\u0964 ","created_at":"2016-10-10 13:18:37","updated_at":"2016-10-10 13:18:37"},{"id":3,"ar":"\u0642\u0644","en":"say","bn":"\u09ac\u09b2\u09be","desc":"\u09ac\u09b2\u09be\u0964 \u0995\u09a5\u09be \u09ac\u09b2\u09be","created_at":"2016-10-10 13:21:44","updated_at":"2016-10-10 13:21:44"}]
```

this data contain multiple langauge, so , I need to write it as it will be readable not in this format while writing.. it will look like the following format after writing.

```
[{"id":3,"ar":"جاء","en":"come","bn":"আসা","desc":"ثم ذات أكثر اليها, ٣٠ عدد قائمة الشتاء بالمحور, دون خيار جدول بمحاولة بل. بـ وقد ثانية الإمتعاض, أوروبا البولندي مع أضف, عجّل والمعدات كل قبل. وقوعها، تزامناً الجديدة، عل مدن, جهة أم جدول وشعار الآلاف. عل عدد أمام الضغوط الولايات. كلّ أم فكان وبدأت تسمّى. حين بل ويتّفق المشتّتون, ذلك مايو لعدم كل.\r\n\r\nان نقطة مايو اللازمة مدن, هذا عل لغزو إبّان, لم ومضى التجارية حين. أسيا واتّجه التجارية بـ انه. أي يتم ببعض بينما الأرض, هذا تصفح كثيرة التخطيط إذ, قام أم منتصف فقامت ليتسنّى. شيء ما أمدها الشمل, حادثة اسبوعين إذ كلا.\r\n\r\nأي الدمج تكبّد الأسيوي الا. تم الشتاء الهادي بمحاولة هذا. ليركز فقامت بين و, فقد لكون بخطوط شاسعة عن. من العالم إيطاليا المتاخمة نفس, أخذ والمانيا الدولارات أن. ما انه فقامت مهمّات المتاخمة, ان ساعة كُلفة النزاع فقد. أضف من نقطة سياسة والمانيا.\r\n\r\nطوكيو الفترة التكاليف أي نفس. المشترك واقتصار بلا من, عن دار هنا؟ الأمور أوروبا. يبق ان السيء التبرعات, قام جديدة التاريخ، ما, ٣٠ يتبقّ الأرضية وتم. إذ مسرح ليرتفع ومحاولة فقد.\r\n\r\nأضف قتيل، الشمال الأوروبيّون أي, ما بقعة تسمّى تعد. كل وحتّى الدول للصين أضف, عدد وعلى مشارف أي, ودول الأرض مليارات حيث ما. وتم عن هنا؟ الحرة, ثمّة إعادة أن مما, جهة نهاية وقدّموا من. لفشل جسيمة جُل عل, حصدت سقوط والكوري عل مدن, مع فهرست واقتصار لها. ٣٠ انتصارهم الأمريكية حين, بالرّد للأراضي الإقتصادية ومن و, لها تكبّد الإقتصادية ما.\r\n\r\nما جُل أصقاع العصبة, إيو بـ وأزيز عليها أطراف, حين أم دأبوا أدوات الأهداف. هذه بـ أدوات بالمحور الأوروبية،, بال إذ عُقر بخطوط تسمّى. بقصف اتّجة لإعلان ثم يتم, فمرّ العاصمة وبلجيكا، كل دار, كل انه أوسع بهيئة الأثنان. بال ان جسيمة تحرّك الإقتصادية, تطوير تصرّف عل حول. ثمّة فبعد ذلك كل, كل جُل بأيدي اليابان،. أم فقد واستمر المؤلّفة.\r\n\r\nثم وفرنسا الأمريكية جُل, بحث الحكم والفلبين عن. وصغار مقاطعة ومن ان, بشرية وباءت وأكثرها كان عن, أم الأحمر الساحة عرض. تصفح ويتّفق انه بل, بل بها رئيس هاربر. أخر أي كنقطة الإثنان البشريةً. دون وعلى يتسنّى تغييرات ان, واشتدّت واعتلاء قبل ثم, يتبقّ بأضرار بمعارضة قد الى. لها ببعض استبدال الفرنسي قد, تحت بأضرار لليابان للإتحاد لم.\r\n\r\nاتّجة وبعدما أي كلّ, مرجع وإقامة الإمداد تم كلا. حين إعلان الأرواح ثم. وسمّيت بلديهما والروسية بحث أي, معارضة بالإنزال الإقتصادية أضف بل, بلا تم الأمم السادس وبالتحديد،. دول وبدأت علاقة الجنود ثم, وبدون أعمال ديسمبر ومن كل.\r\n\r\nفي شواطيء الشهيرة الأثنان إيو. مشاركة اسبوعين أم الى, هو إيو بقصف انذار. تمهيد وإقامة هو كلا, في لمّ قِبل بأيدي, شيء وكسبت بتخصيص بل. بتحدّي الضغوط المزيفة هذا هو. أخر رجوعهم المنتصر الساحلية ان.\r\n\r\nالجو شاسعة العناد لان عن, أن إجلاء وحرمان بريطانيا-فرنسا تلك. لم لمّ أمّا الشرقي لمحاكم, هُزم يتعلّق ألمانيا انه ٣٠. فقد عن عقبت الهادي والنرويج, قد ٠٨٠٤ شعار تشكيل بعد. ان نقطة والكوري ماليزيا، يكن, فصل كانت العالم، بالإنزال تم. ٣٠ ومطالبة الجديدة، استراليا، تعد, يونيو محاولات فقد قد.\r\n      ","created_at":null,"updated_at":"2016-09-13 22:25:34"},{"id":4,"ar":"ذهب","en":"go","bn":"যাওয়া","desc":"যাওয়া  This is considered as going anywhere!","created_at":null,"updated_at":"2016-09-13 06:22:21"},{"id":6,"ar":"شكرا","en":"Thanks","bn":"ধন্যবাদ ","desc":"ধন্যবাদ আপনাকে স্যার ","created_at":"2016-09-13 03:52:22","updated_at":"2016-09-13 03:52:22"},{"id":7,"ar":"السلام","en":"Peace","bn":"শান্তি ","desc":"শান্তি । ইসলাম একটি শান্তির ধর্ম।","created_at":"2016-09-13 06:25:12","updated_at":"2016-09-13 06:25:12"},{"id":8,"ar":"رفيق","en":"Friend","bn":"বন্ধু ","desc":"আমার একজন ভাল বন্ধু আছে। ","created_at":"2016-09-13 06:35:08","updated_at":"2016-09-13 06:35:08"},{"id":9,"ar":"كرسي","en":"chair","bn":"কেদারা ","desc":"কেদারা , চেয়ার , বসার চেয়ার । ","created_at":"2016-09-13 06:48:14","updated_at":"2016-09-13 06:48:14"},{"id":10,"ar":"علي","en":"above","bn":"উপরে ","desc":"উপরে ","created_at":"2016-09-13 17:38:30","updated_at":"2016-09-17 05:29:22"},{"id":11,"ar":"الحمد","en":"All praises","bn":"সমস্ত প্রশংসা ","desc":"সমস্ত প্রশংসা  আল্লাহর জন্য ","created_at":"2016-09-17 05:07:24","updated_at":"2016-09-17 05:07:24"},{"id":12,"ar":"قل","en":"say","bn":"বল ","desc":"কোন কিছু বলার জন্য আদেশ করা। ","created_at":"2016-09-17 05:08:35","updated_at":"2016-09-17 05:08:35"}]
```

I am using laravel 5.3 and writing code is

```
 Storage::disk('public')->put('file.txt', $data);
```

Any help from expert?

Many Thanks

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Comment: That's english, Bangla and arabic langugae combined in a json format. what's the other type you mean in laravel 5.3? can you write file with different language data except English?  I need that just.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the second argument, you get the `\uxxxx` codes instead of utf8:

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

For other issues see [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

Answer (score 0):

I have tried writing your json data into a file using 
file_put_contents() function, and it saved json with same characters.

Might Storage::disk('public')->put() filter the input string and add own definition to it.