# How to read and send arabic to database using mysqli

Tags: php, android

This code is for the `mysql_`, I want to change it to `mysqli_`.

Here is my code:

```
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'"); 
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

The connection string is:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(host,user,password,database) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

Comment: Show us you connection code please

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect(host,user,password,database) or die('Unable to Connect');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Comment: you can't mix mysql_ and mysqli_