# Arabic text from SQL Server converting to question marks in front end in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, unicode, nvarchar

I have Arabic text in my SQL Server. When I run the application I am getting question marks in the front end (ASP.NET MVC application).

I have another database with Arabic content. When I switch to that database it is displaying properly.

Is it the database setting somewhere I need to set?

Thanks

Comment: What's the data type of the column that is returning ?  I assume it isn't nvarchar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the database to utf8 ? That should be the trick

Comment: Setting database to UTF-8? I didn't get it.

Comment: Column Datatype is NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database