# Mysql cuts some Arabic strings

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

MYSQL field has type text utf8_general_ci

After connect to DB I call mysqli_set_charset("utf8");

Before insert all string "escaping" with mysqli_real_escape_string()

And sometimes some arabic string saves as not full (the string is truncated to a certain character)

I have no test string, this happens sometimes, during site works...

Comment: Check the answer in the stackoverflow [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Comment: @Elby in my table all collations set to utf8_general_ci but sometimes string cuts and saves as not full... And why string CUTS, they must be saved, but with error characters...

Comment: show the schema

Comment: ... and give an example query with example result

Comment: Check field length, if it is long string, use TEXT field instead of varchar(255).