# Arabic language not store in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Arabic language not store in mysql/php

i'm try to insert this query but it is store **???? ???? ?? ????**.

`INSERT INTO school_name (en_school_name, ar_school_name) VALUES ('some data', 'روضة احمد بنبل')`

For solution i have add this

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conn,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

and also prefer this Question but not work in my case, [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

if i'm run query manually it's work fine but when i'm try to insert query with this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO school_name (en_school_name, ar_school_name)
        VALUES ('".$dat_val_en."', '".$dat_val_ar."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
    echo "<br>";
}
```

it is store **???? ???? ?? ????**. 
**Table structure**

[image]

Comment: this is my database structure  :: http://prntscr.com/gkj5o6

Comment: Checkout this post. This may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Comment: @Pankaj Makwana : yes i did it but not work in my case .

Answer (score 3):

Change your database structure from

```
utf8
```

To

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

The charset of the database needs to be `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Also you can set to database like this also

```
CREATE DATABASE databasename
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Drop the table and recreate it pls

Comment: i have create new table and add **utf8_unicode_ci** but it is not work http://prntscr.com/gkjdwj

Comment: Maybe it can be helpful

Answer (score 2):

To read ,write and sort Arabic text in mysql database using php correctly, make sure that:

1- MySQL charset: **UTF-8 Unicode** (utf8)

2- MySQL connection collation: **utf8_general_ci**

3- your database and table collations are set to: **utf8_general_ci** or **utf8_unicode_ci**

Then, add this code in your php script when you connect to db:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

for more details:
http://www.adviesenzo.nl/examples/php_mysql_charset_fix/

Comment: thanks for answer, i did it but it's not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set you db Character set to UTF-8 And Collation toutf8_general_ci

Comment: yes i did it , this is my database structure :: prntscr.com/gkj5o6 but it is not work in my case. thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin;
```

Note : At a time of creating the table please use below :-
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName`(`col` varchar(100) collate utf8_ general_ci);
```

worked for me

try the collation `utf8_general_ci`