# How to retrive Data from sql server databse using unicode language to urdu

Tags: php, mysqli, utf8mb4

```
mysqli_query($con,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8mb4');
```

Using select query i get

```
 :Ã˜Â¬Ã˜Â¯Ã›Å’Ã˜Â«: Ã˜Â-Ã˜Â¶Ã™Ë†Ã˜Â±Ã˜ÂµÃ™â€žÃ›Å’Ã¯Â•Â²Ã˜Â¹Ã™â€žÃ›Å’Ã›Â Ã™Ë†Ã˜Â³Ã™â€žÃ™â€¦ Ã™â€ Ã›â€™ Ã™ÂÃ˜Â±Ã™â€¦Ã˜Â§Ã›Å’Ã˜Â§:
```

I want to this format

[image]

Comment: First of all: The data in your database needs to be in UTF-8. Then how did you produce that output? Remember that the browser needs to know it's UTF-8 and the font you use must be able to display the characters.

Comment: Set meta charset `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: not working i all ready use this keyword: Saad Suri

Comment: follow this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database

Comment: Anand Pandey use these link still not workingg

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  If that does not suffice, then provide some more details, as indicated in that Q&A.  It may even be "double encoded.  Please provide HEX of a few of the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text has been mangled twice.

1. start with `Ã˜Â±Ã˜Âµ`
2. treat that as if it were erroneously converted through latin1, I get `Ø±Øµ`.  (The "Mojibake" of that is what is in step 1.)
3. Again, doing an un-Mojibake, I see `رص`, which is probably part of that png.  That's Arabic REH and SAD; does that sound likely?

See "Mojibake" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for the likely causes.  But, then, realize that the mangling was done twice!

Dig through how the text is processed.  But keep in mind that there are at least 2 *sequential* mistakes.  Perhaps even copying the data from one table/database/system to another, with each one doing its own Mojibake?

(I have been chasing charset problems for years; this is, I think, a new scenario to me!)

Undoing one stage:

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('Ø±Øµ' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4) --> `رص`
```

(Sorry if I have lost the right-to-left vs left-to-right.)

But you need to avoid latin1 at *all* stages.  `mysqli_set_charset` and `<meta>` are only two parts of the picture.

Longer string:

```
`Ã˜Â¬Ã˜Â¯Ã›Å’Ã˜Â«: Ã˜Â-Ã˜Â¶Ã™Ë†` --> `Ø¬Ø¯ÛŒØ«` --> `جدیث`
```