# arabic doesn't load well even the character encoding is ut8_general_ci

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, browser

i would like to have an answer about the problem that am facing which is   the arabic languages do load in random way in the data base and the browser (some times it does work correctly ,sometimes doesnt , by showing a multiple symbols) even i have set all the character encoding ti utf8_general_ci

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your database collation in order to work with Arabic language.

For MS SQL SERVER
=> Go to properties of your database 
=> Click on option tab on the left side and change your collation to Arabic_CI_AS.

For MY SQL
[Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

This will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you so much ,but in the collation options the Arabic_CI _AS doesn't existe!

Comment: Welcome! Which sql server are you using?

Comment: i tried wamp xampp appserver , at the moment am using xampp

Comment: Then go with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database