# How to solve Arabic value problem in Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I use an Arabic value in an HQL query, it returns null.

I added the unicode and UTF in MySQL datasource.

I got SQL generated from the Hibernate query and ran it in workbench, and it gave me a result:

```
Query q = se.createQuery("from Days where d_name = 'الخميس' " );
```

I run the generated SQL query on workbench and it gives me a result. I also tried to query with d_id and it runs without problems, so i think that the problem is with Arabic values.

I expect the result to come back as an object, 
but it returns null!

Comment: Add `N` befor arabic value, try `se.createQuery("from Days where d_name = N'الخميس' " );`

Comment: Pleas confirm which database you are using - if it’s a syntax thing, we need to know to help you

Answer (score 0):

Although Adding `N` before arabic values might solve you problem but Prefixing all values with N can cause horrific performance issues - often, this will cause queries to result in full table scans rather than index lookups.

You can find out a way by using utf-8 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)