# php web application not support Arabic language in server

Tags: php, web-applications, localhost, remote-server, arabic-support

My php Web application not supporting Arabic language. I want to add data from a form and display the table in browser. When I type Arabic letters it store some other characters(Ø£Ø®Ø¨Ø§Ø±
Ø£Ø®Ø¨Ø§Ø) and display as ????? in browser.

But the same application support Arabic in my local server localhost. How to solve this please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database)

Comment: "Support Arabic" is a very broad concept. But using UTF-8 should be the basic foundation. You're possibly relying on defaults rather that setting encoding explicitly.

Comment: I add this code ----->  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4'); --------------  with connection and this worked :) .

Answer (score 1):

To store any kind language in database you need to set collation **utf8_unicode_ci**

utf8_unicode_ci should support almost all language

Follow the steps:

1. Go to phpMyadmin
2. Select table's column that is storing data
3. edit collation to utf8_unicode_ci

That's all it should work.